# Simple sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a question for a SQL query. Suppose we have:

```
cinema
  name 
  id_cinema 
  cinema 
  city

movies
  id_movie 
  name_movie
```

suppose that:

- a movie can be seen in more cinema;
- in a cinema you can see different movies;

I have a relationship between the tables of type: many to many. I need therefore a table `cinema-movie` which has primary keys `id_cinema` `id_film`.

Is there a sql query that allows me to have all the movies in a cinema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query would be

```
select m.* from movies m left join cinema_movie mc on m.id = mc.movie_id where mc.cinema_id = 1;
```

E.g.

```
mysql> select * from movies;
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | movie1 |
|    2 | movie2 |
|    3 | movie3 |
|    4 | movie4 |
+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from cinema;
+------+-------+---------+
| id   | name  | cinema  |
+------+-------+---------+
|    1 | name1 | cinema1 |
|    2 | name2 | cinema2 |
|    3 | name3 | cinema3 |
|    4 | name4 | cinema4 |
+------+-------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from cinema_movie;
+----------+-----------+
| movie_id | cinema_id |
+----------+-----------+
|        1 |         1 |
|        3 |         1 |
|        4 |         1 |
|        1 |         3 |
|        3 |         3 |
+----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select m.* from movies m left join cinema_movie mc on m.id = mc.movie_id where mc.cinema_id = 1;
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | movie1 |
|    3 | movie3 |
|    4 | movie4 |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The `left join` is useless with this `where` clause. An inner join is enough - and would give same results.

Answer (score 2):

Show all movies from cinema 10:

```
SELECT movies.*
FROM movies
JOIN cinema_movie ON cinema_movie.id_film = movies.id_movie
WHERE cinema_movie.id_cinema = 10
```

With a `JOIN` like this (inner join), you can either select from `movies` and join `cinema_movie`, or vice versa - the ordering doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Query with cinema information:

```
select * from movies as m
join cinema_movie as cm
on m.id_movie = cm.id_movie
join cinema as c
on c.id_cinema = cm.id_cinema
where c.id_cinema = <your id_cinema>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
cinema
  name
  id_cinema
  cinema
  city

movies
  id_movie
  name_movie

cinema_movie
  id_cinema
  id_movie
  start_time
```

Then you can join by:

```
SELECT cinema_movies.id_cinema, name, cinema, cinema_movies.id_movie, name_movie
FROM cinema, movies, cinema_movies
WHERE cinema.id_cinema = cinema_movies.id_cinema
  AND movies.id_movie = cinema_movies.id_movie
  AND cinema_movies.id_cinema = 'northpark12'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to seach by `cinema.name`:

```
SELECT cinema.name
     , movies.*
FROM movies 
  INNER JOIN cinema_movie
    ON cinema_movie.id_film = movies.id_movie
  INNER JOIN cinema
    ON cinema_movie.id_cinema = cinema.id_cinema
WHERE cinema.name = "YourCinemaName"
```

If you want to search by `id_cinema`:

```
SELECT cinema.name
     , movies.*
FROM movies 
  INNER JOIN cinema_movie
    ON cinema_movie.id_film = movies.id_movie
  INNER JOIN cinema
    ON cinema_movie.id_cinema = cinema.id_cinema
WHERE cinema.id_cinema = YourCinemaID
```

If you want to search for a specific cinema.id and you don't want to output cinema's name, Box9's answer is enough.

Comment: I use Microsoft Access... with you query by Name i have sintax error... why?
(ps: what'is the join type (inner, left...) can i have some join after the from operator?

Comment: @GgSalent: Didn't you have a `MYSQL` tag in your question? If you use Access, add that tag in your queation. Access needs `INNER JOIN` and/or paranthesis too, I think. I'll check.